# Incredible Night Wave Light System

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, fireplace

I want to buy or make a nice night random-waves light projector at home.
The idea is from the movie ["Blade Runner 2049"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856101/):
[image]
I searched on sale, but I did not find anything like this.
There are many [more primitive goods](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N6GN6OK).
There is another option - some [Ultra High Definition Home Theater Projector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071P6KQZH). But it is practically inconvenient...

Well, this is a difficult task. Of course, it is almost impossible to create an effect, looks like a professional Hollywood movie.

But today I've seen *the other very good idea* in the trailer to the ["The Greatest Showman"](https://www.foxmovies.com/movies/the-greatest-showman) movie :)
(Rotation of the cylinder with holes around the candle).
[image]
[image]

Such a simple trick will never looks like the trailer. *But in any case it's a useful and a good idea.*

Any ideas how the ideas of the "ocean reflections" waves and a real natural fire can be made on practice?

Comment: Projector light.  Fan. Sheets of transparent plastic (Saran Wrap but not sticky).

Comment: this site ... https://www.rogerdeakins.com/lighting-2/blade-runner-2049-water-reflection-effect/  says this ... (not sure if it is the same scene though) ...  `The water was lit with 10K Fresnel lamps. There were two per side making eight in all. It was a very tricky rig because it had to be quite high, so as to not be in shot, and the lamps had to have the right angle to reflect and spill across the wall as they do. I was originally expecting that I could do this effect without lighting the water so much.`

Comment: `The bottom of the pool had been painted black so, in my naiveté, I thought it would stay quite dark.  Consequently I asked my gaffer, Billy O'Leary, to constructed long barn door extenders so that the pattern of light on the water would be a pleasing symetrical shape and the light from the two lamps would merge together.`

Comment: look for gel projectors and "effects projector", where i found something like this for cheap: https://www.ebay.com/itm/360962061264 probably not as cool as photo-shopped movie frames, but a lot cheaper! you could probably grease the lens of some of the starry ones as well.

Comment: @dandavis , I have already ordered such a projector, but I think that it is rather primitive

Comment: *...are off-topic as they have little in common with the other ... tasks discussed here* - this is an unconstructive reason

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a UHD projector - you could probably use one or more "discarded or for sale cheap as not new enough" projectors at HD or lower resolution. This sort of thing seems quite common (if tacky, to my taste) in modern art installations for the sort of effect you seek - best example I recall as closest to yours was raindrop ripples all over the floor, and I happened to recognize the 1080P projectors they were using.

As for water ripples (specifically), any point light source (need not be a projector - some LEDs would work well), a (clear) tank of water, and a ripple generator of some sort. We used to do this with overhead projectors and a 12x12x1 inch tank to illustrate waves in physics classes. Bounce off mirrors if you need it anywhere other than under the projector, gravity is uncompromising when it comes to water.

But do realize that when looking at movies these days, most of the effects are added in post-production and never got any more realistic than numbers in a computer. So what you see and how it appears that they did it are generally unrelated.

Comment: Could you attach a schematic or a photo of your system?